# How to extract codec and bitrate from an internet stream using androidX media3 libraries?

Tags: android, androidx, android-media3

I am using the AndroidX media3 component, and have it playing internet radio audio steams, (MP3/FLAC/HLS/MP4 etc).  I would like to display codec and bitrates within the UI of my Android app, however I am having trouble finding where to even start with this, I have looked at the docs, and also looked at the interfaces available in my app, and not come up with very much at all.

The closest I have come to something is from the getAudioFormat interface that the player provides.

```
player.getAudioFormat().sampleMimeType
```

This works, and I can work out the codec type, however the following don't work, and always return -1

```
player.getAudioFormat().sampleRate
player.getAudioFormat().averageBitrate
player.getAudioFormat().bitrate
```

My question, I guess, is twofold:

1/ Am I approaching this problem correctly, as above, and if so, is this a bug, where the bitrates are not shown.
2/ If not, what is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `AnalyticsListener`. You'll receive an `onTracksChanged` event, it has `Tracks` object with available tracks. Each track has a format and the format contains information about codecs.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/common/Format#codecs()

Comment: Thanks, I have been down this deadend already.   Some streams, this information isn't populated.   [link](https://ibb.co/K7QmHVs)

Comment: I currently have a hybrid approach, where I work out the codec from the stream type, this is 100% reliable, it's always present and correct.   The Bitrate information however is rather hit and miss.  Some provide it within the metadata of the track, others don't.  There is no way to ask media3 to work it out?